# Scaling data between 0 and 1

Tags: r

I want to scale my dataframe `protein` such that the values are between 0 and 1.

```
protein <- (protein - min(protein)) / (max(protein) - min(protein))
```

Traceback:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric-alike variables
```

I tried `unlist` but the error persisted.

```
> typeof(protein)
[1] "list"
```

Data:

```
> dput(protein)
structure(list(TCGA.A3.3357.01 = c("0.43216667125", "0.27655395325", 
"-0.05052052725"), TCGA.A3.3367.01 = c("0.22529132975", "-0.12950190925", 
"0.00483883425000009"), TCGA.A3.3387.01 = c("0.0428932150000005", 
"0.0548635820000001", "0.0339660955000001")), row.names = c("14-3-3_beta", 
"14-3-3_epsilon", "14-3-3_zeta"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you want to rescale each column by the max/min of that column, or rescale based on the max/min of the whole data frame? You're currently getting this error because you've stored the numeric values as characters (you can't subtract a character vector).

Comment: (1) `typeof(mtcars)` returns `list` even though we know it's a frame, "type" is not the same as "class". It is often more informative to use `class(protein)` here. (2) Your values are all strings. While you _can_ repair it with `protein[] <- lapply(protein, as.numeric)`, I **strongly** suggest you go back through your data-munging pipeline and fix where the problem originates, i.e., which step changes it from what was originally a number into a string. It is _far_ better to fix that then try to recover from strings. (3) Once you've fixed that, then your original code should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your columns to `numeric` and use `apply`

```r
df_out <- apply(protein, 2, \(x) {x <- as.numeric(x); (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))}) |> as.data.frame()
rownames(df_out) <- rownames(protein)

protein
               TCGA.A3.3357.01     TCGA.A3.3367.01    TCGA.A3.3387.01
14-3-3_beta      0.43216667125       0.22529132975 0.0428932150000005
14-3-3_epsilon   0.27655395325      -0.12950190925 0.0548635820000001
14-3-3_zeta     -0.05052052725 0.00483883425000009 0.0339660955000001
```

**data**

```r
protein <- structure(list(TCGA.A3.3357.01 = c("0.43216667125", "0.27655395325", 
"-0.05052052725"), TCGA.A3.3367.01 = c("0.22529132975", "-0.12950190925", 
"0.00483883425000009"), TCGA.A3.3387.01 = c("0.0428932150000005", 
"0.0548635820000001", "0.0339660955000001")), row.names = c("14-3-3_beta", 
"14-3-3_epsilon", "14-3-3_zeta"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This code returned all NA values

Comment: It does work with the dataframe provided

Answer (score 0):

an approach with {dplyr}:

```
library(dplyr)

looks_numeric <- \(xs) !all(is.na(as.double(xs)))
scale_to_unit <- \(xs) (xs-min(xs, na.rm = TRUE))/
                        diff(range(xs, na.rm = TRUE)
                        )


protein |>
   mutate(across(where(looks_numeric), ~ as.numeric(.x))) |>
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ scale_to_unit(.x)))
```

**edit** as [Julien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8806649/julien) pointed out, both `across`-`mutate`s can be lumped:

```
protein |>
mutate(across(where(looks_numeric), ~ as.numeric(.x)),
       across(where(is.numeric), ~ scale_to_unit(.x))
       )
```

```
##                TCGA.A3.3357.01 TCGA.A3.3367.01 TCGA.A3.3387.01
## 14-3-3_beta          1.0000000       1.0000000       0.4271863
## 14-3-3_epsilon       0.6776117       0.0000000       1.0000000
## 14-3-3_zeta          0.0000000       0.3786452       0.0000000
```

Comment: You could do this in one `mutate`

Comment: Julien, thanks for pointing that out! (Thought I could use only one `across` per `mutate` ... until now).